# Counting number of lines, words and characters while taking input as a string in loop

Tags: c, string

I am trying to solve the following problem in C language.
The input is taken as strings and user enters each string in new line. While user enters "END" , the program must stop taking input and should display the number of lines , words and characters. To achieve this I wrote the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<string.h>
void main(){
 char a[100], b = {'E', 'N', 'D'};
 int i, k, word = 0, chr = 0, line = 0 ;
 printf("Enter paragraph (enter END to stop)\n");
 gets(a);
 k = strcmp(a,b);
 while (k != 0 ){
    line++;
    for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (a[i] == ' ')
           word++;
        else 
            chr++;
     }
     gets(a);
     k = strcmp(a,b);

   }
  printf("%d %d %d\n", line, word, chr );
 }
```

In the above code I assumed that the user is using only space button to give spaces between words.
The problems was
as soon as I give first input I get an error message saying program has stopped working.

I am not able to see whether my logic is wrong or my usage of syntax is wrong.

Comment: Never ***ever*** use `gets`. It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) it have even been removed from the C language standard. Use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the variable declaration

```
 char a[100], b = {'E', 'N', 'D'};
```

`b` is declared as a scalar. This will lead to Segmentation Fault in `strcmp(a,b)` because both arguments of `strcmp()` must be pointers.

It should be

```
 char a[100], b[] = "END";
```

you have to add `[]` to make `b` an array and you don't need to put each characters separately. Using string literal style initialization also have the compiler add terminating null-character so that you can pass that to `strcmp()` safely.

One more note is that you shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated in C99 and removed from C11. You can use `fgets()`, which can specify the length of the buffer, instead. `fgets()` stores newline character while `gets()` doesn't, so you have to remove that manually. This can be done like this, for example.

```
char a[100];
char *lf;
fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
if ((lf = strchr(a, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';
```

Also I suggest you should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.

Comment: Mike, what if I do `char b[2] = { x, '\0'} ;` where x is a char variable ?

Comment: It is fine provided that `x` has properly set some value before that.